# What is proper way to get data from the database using a view to call the controller?

Tags: codeigniter, view

I am making a program that deal with multiple tables (recipe, instructions on how to make, directions, etc. ) and I am already able to add new recipe and save the data provided in the input form to the proper table having foreign keys to link each one.

What I did was after the insertion of a new recipe, I would get the latest id of the inserted recipe then get it from the model to the controller and from the controller, I would pass the id to the view like this:

```
$data['recipe_id'] = $this->recipe_model->id;
$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

Then in the view, I would be able to have the passed id simply by doing:

```
<?php echo $recipe_id ?>
```

I tried to print the id and I did got the right one. Now, I was wondering on how to pass the id to a controller method so that I can query again the information about the new recipe and for me to display it or is my solution is not an efficient one and there is another better way of solving it.

If so, I would be glad to hear from you. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the actual model object, instead of the id:

```
$data['recipe'] = $this->recipe_model;
$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

This way there is no need to call back into a controller to get the recipe information.

If you truly insist, you can implement a [helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) function or [library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) function that uses the `CI` object to load your model, but you're much better off simply copying the saved recipe object into the view data.

Comment: I see. I had that one coming but I was thinking that it would be easier for me to do but I know it's not that efficient. Is there a chance that I could redirect the user to the same page as viewing a single recipe and the successful adding of recipe?

Comment: By the way, I never tried passing the whole model object. I would like to ask if what are the data that can be included as I would pass it to the view? Will it be all the variables inside the recipe_model? And how will I be able to display them on the view?

Comment: You can pass any PHP object to the view as described at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html (look at the section about adding dynamic data): if you did it like the code above then you can just use the `$recipe` object in your view. So if your recipe has a property `name` you would use `<?= $recipe->name ?>` to print it out in the view.

Comment: What is I got an array property let's say $data['recipename'] will it work like $recipe->data['recipename']? Am I getting it right?

Comment: Ah. I got it now. I just used the model and controller then pass the info to the view then do the displaying there. Thanks.